# Changing accessoryType for a row in a sectioned tableView after user selects the row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a sectioned tableView that I want my user to select one item from the table.  When they select the item, a check should appear next to the item (using `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`).  If they had made a previous selection, the check should be removed from the previously selected row.  Here is the code I am using:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int newRow = [indexPath row];

    int oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];

    if (newRow != oldRow || newRow == 0)
    {

        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: lastIndexPath]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        [lastIndexPath release];
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;  
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

`lastIndexPath` is declared privately in the `.h` file.

This code works great for a small list that is not sectioned.  But in a large table that is sectioned, it puts random check marks in rows in other sections.  It is almost as if the  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is ignoring the section in indexPath.

The code also crashes if I select a row that is greater than the number of rows in the smallest section.

Here is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];

    NSArray *itemSection = [items objectForKey:key];

    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    NSArray *rowLabel = [itemSection objectAtIndex:row]; 

    cell.textLabel.text = [rowLabel objectAtIndex:1];

    NSString *detText = [rowLabel objectAtIndex:0];

    detText = [detText stringByAppendingString:@"            $"];

    detText = [detText stringByAppendingString:[rowLabel objectAtIndex:2]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = detText;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: need to see your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I am assuming that you are dequeuing cells and using a reuse identifier (the default implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`). If that is the case, then your code for creating cells will reuse the check marked cell as a template to create a new cell. To solve this problem, you can do a few things: "create a new cell each time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" or "keep a reference to each cell and circumvent the calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`"

Comment: Yes - I see what you are saying and this could resolve the first problem of the random checkmarks, but I don't think it would resolve the second problem of crashing if I select a row greater than the number of rows in the smallest section.  Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

Comment: you wont be able to post that code into a comment. Add it into your original post

Answer (score 0):

One problem you are having here is how you are saving the indexPath in lastIndexPath.  You need to retain the indexPath you are saving in lastIndexPath.  the indexPath passed into this method is autoreleased so it will likely get released out from under you if you don't retain it.  This could be causing your crash.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably exactly what you are looking for. I developed this for one of my apps. Enjoy ! (if so please mark as answered)
Also note that I'm using ARC, so no retain and release.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   /* 
    1. First we get the indexPath from the prior priorSelectedRowInteger and priorSelectedSectionInteger ivars. Note: we could use a single indexPath ivar, but we separate them into row and section here for clarity.
    2. Then we reset the selectedRowInteger ivar to the currently selected row. This must be done before any rows are reloaded.
    3. Then we reload only the two rows at the concerned index paths, as we have captured the indexPath of the prior selected row and the method gives us the new one.  We could just simply reload the table here with [self.tableView reloadData], but it would not be animated and not as smooth.

    */
    NSIndexPath *priorSelectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:priorSelectedRowInteger inSection: priorSelectedSectionInteger];
     // Now that we have the priorSelectedIndexPath, we save the new one for the next round.
     self.priorSelectedRowInteger = indexPath.row; 
     self.priorSelectedSectionInteger = indexPath.section;

    // For a changing tableView, check to make sure the priorIndexPath is still valid before trying to reload the prior row.
   // NSLog(@"priorSelectedIndexPath %@", priorSelectedIndexPath);
     if ((tableView.numberOfSections >= priorSelectedIndexPath.section+1) && ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:priorSelectedIndexPath.section] >= priorSelectedIndexPath.row+1)) {
    NSArray *thePriorIndexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:priorSelectedIndexPath];
   [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:thePriorIndexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}


    // Reload only the selected indexPath - necessary to update the text colors etc.
    NSArray *theIndexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:theIndexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```